# Is a message inspector really the only way to remove unwanted attributes from the s:Body tag?

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, .net-4.0

I have a WCF service (.Net 4 hosted in IIS 7.5) adding unwanted attributes to the s:Body tag in the response.

```
 <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Implementing a message inspector seems like a lot of trouble to go through to get a simple

```
<s:Body>
```

Am I missing an easier way of doing this or do I really have to do the extra work with the message inspector?

Comment: Why do you want to remove those attributes? They're harmless.

Comment: The client (that I have no control over) blows up trying to parse those attributes.

Comment: Another client code parsing XML as text ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did indeed have to implement a message inspector. Lame.

Comment: The lame thing is that your client doesn't understand basic XML.

Comment: Yes well the multinational corp that wrote the client I had to cater to isn't interested in others people's opinions. (And it's pretty obvious if you've ever driven one of the vehicles they sell)